# Javascript user name validation

Tags: javascript, validation

For this homework I have to write code that checks if a user name is valid shown below, but how would the last alert look if the first two alerts exist?

```
    function isUserNameValid(user) {
    "use strict";
    var alert = "";
    if (user.length > 12) {
    alert("cannot be more than 12 letters long");
    return false;
  }
    alert = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (!alert.test(user)) {
    alert("must only use letters A-Z or a-z");
    return false;
  }
    alert = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;     //<--(this part is the question?)
    if(user.length > 12 || if(!alert.test(user)) {
    alert("must only use letters A-Z or a-z and cannot be more than 12 letters long)";
    return false;
 }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Don't use "alert" as a variable name or else none of that will work.

Comment: it will never reach the 3rd alert as it is checking the same in first two alert. Put the 3rd if condition at the top and use '&&' instead of '||'. see the code in below answer

Answer (score 0):

put first if as below and after that rest of the two

```
if(user.length > 12 && if(!a.test(user)) {   
 alert("must only use letters A-Z or a-z and cannot be more than 12 letters long)";   return false; 
}
```

Comment: The site I am using to run the code gives me an error saying unexpected if (the if(!a.test(user))) and if I take it out I get expected token )?